# Android app + MySQL bad performance

Tags: android, wampserver, database-performance, query-performance

This is the scenario:

- 8 tablets creating data and everytime they make a change uploading it to a MySQL database (They just need to refresh 1 line per each one)
- 5 tablets monitoring the data and saving as xml files locally every 4 seconds (sometimes they make some changes in the tables, but occasionaly)
- A WAMP server with its respective php files to connect with the MySQL and make the correspondent changes on data.

I have a program that makes this two different things via WiFi, but the problem is that the app works to bad. It stutters and the performance is awful. The only way to improve its performance is extending the 4 seconds of the refresh of the monitoring tabets, but I need it to be as close to real time as possible. It seems like the WAMP server is swamped or that the dataflow the tablets create is too much for the net.

I need some advice, 13 tablets in the same net shouldn't create this type of problems as the info they need to refresh from the MySQL is just a line per each. Maybe doing it with PHP files and MySQL databases wasn't the best choice. Does anyone know where could be the problem? What I should improve? Thanks in advice.

Have a nice code!

Comment: Is the WAMPServer installed on a Desktop OS or a Server OS?

Comment: In a windows 7 enterprise

Comment: Its possible that W7 just cannot cope with all those connections is such a short period, [see this doc](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-many-concurrent-connections-allowed-to-access-a-windows-7-computer/) Desktop OS's are not configured or configurable to manage that many connections. Try running your servier on a server.